# Given a random permutation $\sigma$ of a set $\{1,...,n\}$. Assume we want to compute $X$=# of integers $i$ with $\sigma(i)=i$. What is $E[X]$?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, fixed-points

Given a random permutation $\sigma$ of a set $\{1,...,n\}$. Assume we want to compute $X$=# of integers $i$ with $\sigma(i)=i$. What is the expected value of $X$?

**Potential Solution Part 1**

I had an overly complicated way of calculating this, which was to sum the permutations so $\sum_{i=1}^{n}{n \choose i}-(n-i)$, this should give the number of permutations that contain $i$. Unless I'm misinterpreting this question. The other issue is the formula I have written doesn't simplify well.

**Potential Solution Part 2**
So after getting a better understanding of what $\sigma(i)=i$, which is the case where random permutation $\sigma$ has index $i=i$. Then $X$ represents the number of integers s.t. $\sigma(i)=i$. Writing out some simple examples I see that they equal 1, but not sure why.
$$n=2 \text{ then:} P(X=2)=\frac{1}{2}, P(X=1)=0, P(X=0)=\frac{1}{2}$$
So $E[X]=1$

then if I do $n=3$, number of permutations is $n!=3!=6$.
$$P(X=3)=\frac{1}{6}, P(X=2)=0, P(x=1)=\frac{3}{6}$$
then $E[X]=1$. I've done this for more examples and keep getting 1, but not totally sure why. I'm having trouble simplifying this formula into a summation because of the cases where $P(X=i)=0$ where $i$ is not 0. $P(X=i)=\frac{something}{n!}$, but not sure what the numerator should be.

Comment: This can be calculated pretty easily with linearity of expectation (the simple way). You can also try to compute $E[X]$ directly, but this will be tedious. I think this is what you're trying to do, but it doesn't look like you have written it correctly.

Comment: What is $p$ in your summation? Also how did you get this summation, it doesn't seem like it is correct. You should go back the formula for $E[X]$, which is $\sum_{k=0}^n kP[X=k]$. Also just to make sure you're interpreting the question correctly, $X$ is a random variable that equals the number of elements of the permutation that are in their original spot.

Comment: @AlanAbraham o apologies. I didn't know how to write choose in latex so I copy pasted from a link that used $p$. That $p$ should be $i$. What is $P[X=k]$ in your equation? The probability that number of values in $X=k$?

Comment: Yes, $P[X=k]$ is the probability that $X$ is $k$

Comment: How do you interpret $X$? Based on the question phrasing I interpret it as "number of permutations where number $i$ is in a permutation of the set" then we divide that by number of permutations to get $E[X]$, but that might not be correct.

Comment: Hint: Let $X_i$ be the indicator random variable for the event $\sigma(i) = i$ in permutation $\sigma$. Note that $X = \sum_{i = 1}^n X_i$. Can you solve it from here?

Comment: @sudeep5221 can you verify that my definition for $X_i$ is correct I'm still not sure how to interpret $\sigma(i)=i$. Does $\sigma(i)$ mean the size? Or integer $i$ from the set is in a permutation $\sigma(i)$?

Comment: $\sigma(i)$ is the number on location $i$ in the permutation $\sigma$. Suppose $n = 4$ and $\sigma = \{2, 1, 4, 3\}$, then $\sigma(1) = 2, \sigma(2) = 1, \sigma(3) = 4$ and $\sigma(4) = 3$.

Comment: @Gooby your original interpretation of $X$ is not the correct one. $X$ should be a random variable that returns a real number based on an input of a random permutation $\sigma$. In this case it is the number of elements of the permutation that are in their original position. Your interpretation is actually not a random variable.

Comment: @AlanAbraham good point, pointing out my interpretation is not an RV that makes it more obvious the flaw in my thinking.

Comment: "*The formula I have written doesn't simplify well*"  It won't.  The easy approach is (as alluded to already) to take advantage of the linearity of expectation and the punchline is that the answer will be $\frac{1}{n}\times n$ which of course simplifies to just simply $1$.  Any other approach will be needlessly tedious and frustrating if even possible to complete.

Comment: k guess my issue now is a formula for $P[X=i]$ I added to the original question which part I'm having trouble with for formulating this.

Comment: @JMoravitz "**Any** other approach will be needlessly tedious and frustrating ...."  How about Burnside's lemma? The average number of fixed points equals the number of orbits, so for a transitive action that average is $1$. (Yes, I realize that's irrelevant for the OP.)